# AngularJS route config when rendering navigation bar on the server for role based authorization

Tags: angularjs, lift, angularjs-routing

We want to render the navigation bar on the server due to security reasons. In this scenario how to handle the route configuration on the client side using angularjs.

We are using Scala and Lift(sitemap) for rendering the menu on the server side.

It will be great if some one provide any sample applications.

Thankyou all.

Comment: maybe you share your thoughts on how to achieve your goal first

Comment: what kind of server/scriptlanguage? PHP, Java, Node, ....

Comment: The requests should be filtered on the server anyways, do you realize this?

Comment: You mean there is no issue in rendering the navigation bar in client side as long as the request is filtered in the server?

Comment: If you are rendering it on the server, why not use a Lift Snippet? https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Snippets

Comment: We are using Rest Services

Answer (score 0):

Filtering unauthorized requests on the server side takes priority, keep in mind that though a debugger, user-scripts, add-ins the users can do whatever they like with your client side application.

There can be several ways of achieving what your looking for...

1. Deliver an array/object/something of available menu items as a resource.
2. Simply enabling disabling (ng-show) menu items based on a user object provided by a auth service.
3. Switching templates based on Authenticated state.

And probably many more... But if the server endpoint isn't locked down properly, then all the above won't shield your application.

(I believe this is what @flup is referring to as well)

---

As for the routing configuration if you choose to render it on server side however, this is more tricky unless you wan't to fiddle with generating javascript on the server and do full refreshes (yuck, and especially yuck because it leaves us without the ability to cache)...

Since you don't have access to the services during configuration you will have to look else where for making server requests in these blocks, and to ensure the routes are there you may also need to make it a blocking call (normally not what we do).

So far, AFAIK, no routing frameworks directly support a feature that will help you. And I even think https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing is the only one that has it on the roadmap...

Don't think there is any plans for it in ngRoute, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router nor http://angular-route-segment.com/

I could be wrong though.